# What is the best way to implement a PCI compliant shopping cart on a react.js website?

Tags: reactjs, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm facing a real challenging product/engineering problem and need some 2 cents. My team built a website via react.js and we're looking to launch. However, after speaking and getting approved with payment processing, the payment gateway options they offer are NMI and Authorize.net. It looks like these e-commerce platforms really support WordPress, Shopify, Wix, and really those drag, drop and build a website type platforms, nothing custom. I saw that Magento could be an option but I am really looking for a shopping cart plugin I integrate. Kinda like a Paypal API.

I for sure know it's possible, I just don't know where else to look. I want to know if anyone has faced this problem before? The only other option I believe we have is restarting the entire project via WordPress which just isn't possible for us.

So, it's like, I'm looking for a PCI shopping cart plugin that works with NMI or authorize.net and can integrate with react.js

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: If you’ve built your own platform but are unable to build an integration with another, perhaps there are contractors in your area that could help?  You’re asking for a plugin for your custom code, and unless your platform is rather significant I’m not sure what you’re expecting to find.

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that neither NMI nor Auth.net support custom integrations - that isn't true at all. Auth.net: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html. NMI: https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gw/merchants/resources/integration/integration_portal.php#cjs_methodology

Either way... could you clarify what you're trying to achieve with a "shopping cart plugin"? Do you have various items on your website that you're trying to sell? If you can write custom code, do you really need a plugin?